# How to delete data in a .NET MAUI list

Tags: c#, .net, maui, delete-file

I am currently doing a project with the MVVM method in NET MAUI to add, modify and delete drivers.
I have a template that contains the name, first name and number of points of the driver.
Then I have two views each with a model view:
- One that represents the list of my drivers with the possibility to add a driver, to select a driver from the list by going to another page (PageListPilotViewModel).
- And another one which represents the selected driver in another page to be able to modify its data and the possibility of removing it. (ProfilePilotViewModel)
At the moment I can select, add the driver and modify the driver in the other page. But I can't delete the driver in the profile page.
Here is what I have done so far:

-> Models : Pilote Model

```
    public class PiloteModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _nom;
            public string Nom
            {
                get { return _nom; }
                set { _nom = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
            }

            private string _prenom;
            public string Prenom
            {
                get { return _prenom; }
                set { _prenom = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
            }

            private int _points;
            public int Points
            {
                get { return _points; }
                set { _points = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
    }
```

-> View : ProfilPilotePage

```
        <vm:PageListPiloteViewModel></vm:PageListPiloteViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Pilote.Nom, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="{Binding Nom}"></Entry>
        <Entry Text="{Binding Pilote.Prenom}" Placeholder="{Binding Pilote.Prenom}"></Entry>
        <Entry Text="{Binding Pilote.Points}" Placeholder="{Binding Pilote.Points}"></Entry>

            <Button Command="{Binding OnsupprimerPiloteCommand}">
            </Button>
        </StackLayout>
```

-> code behind the profilePilotPage view

```
public partial class ProfilPilotePage : ContentPage
{
    private PageListPiloteViewModel _viewModel;
    public ProfilPilotePage(PageListPiloteViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _viewModel = viewModel;
        _viewModel.SupprimerPiloteClicked += OnSupprimerPiloteClicked;

        BindingContext = _viewModel;


    }

    private void OnSupprimerPiloteClicked(object sender, PiloteModel e)
    {
        _viewModel.ListePilotes.Remove(e);
    }
```

-> model views : PageListPilotViewModel , to be able to delete also the driver in the list

```
public ICommand OnsupprimerPiloteCommand { get; set; }


        public PageListPiloteViewModel()
        {
            ValiderCommand = new Command(AjouterPilote);
            OnsupprimerPiloteCommand = new Command(OnSupprimerPiloteClicked);
            SelectedPilote = new PiloteModel();
            ListePilotes = new ObservableCollection<Models.PiloteModel>();





           
            ListePilotes.Add(new Models.PiloteModel { Nom = "Fabio", Prenom = "Quartaro", Points = 215 });
    }

        private void OnSupprimerPiloteClicked()
        {
            SupprimerPiloteClicked?.Invoke(this, SelectedPilote);
        }
```

->code behind the PageListPiloteView: with the error I encounter on the last :
await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilePilotPage{ BindingContext = viewModel }) :
CS7036 Error None of the specified arguments match the 'viewModel' mandatory parameter of 'ProfilePilotPage.ProfilePilotPage(PageListPilotViewModel)'

```
private async void SelectionnerPilote(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PiloteModel selectedPilote = (PiloteModel)((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem;
        ProfilPiloteViewModel viewModel = new ProfilPiloteViewModel();
        viewModel.Pilote = selectedPilote;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilPilotePage{ BindingContext = viewModel });
    }

}
```

Do you have any idea how to make the specified arguments mandatory please ?

Comment: You should limit the code in your question to a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. All excess code that is irrelevant to the question shouldn't be in the question. Also, your question title and your apparent problem differ from each other. Or are you also having problems deleting a driver record?

Comment: @ewerspej Excuse me, yes I do have a problem removing the driver from the list afterwards. I have not yet been able to test the changes due to the error I encountered

Comment: Then those are probably two different questions. My answer is for the compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mixed up constructor and initializer.

This line

```cs
await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilPilotePage{ BindingContext = viewModel });
```

should be

```cs
await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilPilotePage(viewModel));
```

The reason for this is that you're defining an argument in the signature of the `ProfilPilotePage`'s constructor:

```cs
public ProfilPilotePage(PageListPiloteViewModel viewModel)
{
    //...
}
```

Therefore, you **must** pass the ViewModel argument.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you can try to use the ewerspej's solution or only add a default construction method without any parameter into the ProfilPilotePage to fix the error caused by `await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilePilotPage{ BindingContext = viewModel })` . Such as:

```
public partial class ProfilPilotePage : ContentPage
{
    private PageListPiloteViewModel _viewModel;
    public ProfilPilotePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ProfilPilotePage(PageListPiloteViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        _viewModel.SupprimerPiloteClicked += OnSupprimerPiloteClicked;
        BindingContext = _viewModel;
    }
}
```

And then I saw you used both the mvvm and the code behind. You can remove the `OnSupprimerPiloteClicked(object sender, PiloteModel e)` in the page.cs and change the `OnSupprimerPiloteClicked()` in the view model. Such as:

```
private void OnSupprimerPiloteClicked()
{
   ListePilotes.Remove(SelectedPilote);
}
```

Finally, I saw `SelectedPilote = new PiloteModel();` in your viewmodel. Which item in the list did you want to delete? I think it should be the seleted item not a `new PiloteModel()`.

Comment: Zhang Thank you for your reply. I am trying to delete the selected driver from the profile page. And that it deletes itself in the page containing the list.

Comment: Can you delete the selected item successfully with your code? And did you fixed the error you met? @EloiJahan

Comment: Yes, I solved my mistake. Finally to delete my driver I completely changed my approach, instead of deleting my driver with a command. I used a clicked property on my button and then I linked my driver profile page to my driver list page so that the driver was deleted from both pages. Thanks for your help. @LiyunZhang